# Post request in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm having trouble populating data through a form to a table I have created in my rails app.

I can view the data with my index action but when the create action is triggered in the console nothing is stored persistently in my database?

I am using `resources` in my `config/routes.rb` file

rake routes:

```
                                user_leads GET    /user_leads(.:format)                                                     user_leads#index
                                           POST   /user_leads(.:format)                                                     user_leads#create
                             new_user_lead GET    /user_leads/new(.:format)                                                 user_leads#new
                            edit_user_lead GET    /user_leads/:id/edit(.:format)                                            user_leads#edit
                                 user_lead GET    /user_leads/:id(.:format)                                                 user_leads#show
                                           PATCH  /user_leads/:id(.:format)                                                 user_leads#update
                                           PUT    /user_leads/:id(.:format)                                                 user_leads#update
                                           DELETE /user_leads/:id(.:format)                                                 user_leads#destroy
```

app/controllers/user_leads_controller.rb:

```
class UserLeadsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user_lead = UserLead.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @user_lead = UserLead.new
  end

  def create
    @user_lead = UserLead.new(user_lead_params)
  end

  private

  def user_lead_params
    params.require(:user_lead).permit(:name, :businessname, :phone, :email, :amount)
  end
end
```

app/views/user_leads/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user_lead, url: user_leads_path do |u| %>
  <p>
    <%= u.label :name %>
    <%= u.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :businessname %>
    <%= u.text_field :businessname %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :phone %>
    <%= u.text_field :phone %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :email %>
    <%= u.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb:

`resources :user_leads`

And the output in my console when I make the post request:

```
Started POST "/user_leads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-29 11:28:48 +0100
Processing by UserLeadsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"caJM7oMC7t3ATCnE0AyrnnKMOUi9vn7MPSj7jUadqCQZDQ9DPbUvn7pw5VMsf9+LFyAIxan9qTcBTfuwI2ygjQ==", "user_lead"=>{"name"=>"ffbgd", "businessname"=>"ret", "phone"=>"re", "email"=>"btgrfq"}, "commit"=>"Save User lead"}
No template found for UserLeadsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: You are not saving anything in the create action. You should add `@user_lead.save` after `@user_lead = UserLead.new(user_lead_params)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change create method in controller to:

```
 def create
    @user_lead = UserLead.new(user_lead_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_lead.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_leads_path, notice: 'UserLead was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user_lead }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user_lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#create` instead of `#new`:

```
def create
  @user_lead = UserLead.create(user_lead_params)
end
```

Comment: So just remove `def new` method?  I tried that now the console gives me this: `Started POST "/user_leads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-29 11:35:43 +0100
Processing by UserLeadsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SptciqD58VeIGcxCfjIptBrjvG8tWK+jeNl1pzbrdJAiNB8nHk4wFfIlANWCQV2hf0+N4jkbeFhEvHWaUxp8OQ==", "user_lead"=>{"name"=>"fgbgh", "businessname"=>"fgnhfhjhn", "phone"=>"fngh", "email"=>"fj"}, "commit"=>"Save User lead"}
No template found for UserLeadsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)`

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
def create
  @user_lead = UserLead.create(user_lead_params)
end
```